# Get the timestamp of a file without downloading?

Tags: java

Is it possible to get the timestamp of a file without having to download it fully, if the file is fetched from a `https` link?

If not, is it possible to only fetch some chunks of the file and then check the timestamp before downloading the full file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that You are looking for is the [`HEAD`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) HTTP request. It returns the headers without the content, so depending on the server, and headers it provides, You can experiment with [`Last-Modified`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) and  [`If-Modified-Since`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) and pick the one matching your needs.

Comment: Great, the file indeed offers a `Last-modified` attribute as far as I can see in my browser. Could you point me to how I can only fetch the http HEAD with java? I'm doing the file download with apache `FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file, timeout)`, so that's not of any help with the headers here... Would I have to use `URL` and `URLConnection`?

Comment: I guess, instead of GET send HEAD and read headers...How to do it depends on which framework You use to execute the request, on standard `HttpURLConnection` use `setRequestMethod`